# Nginx conf duplicate issues

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm very new to server admin. Using Digital Ocean, I recently upgrades Ubuntu from v14 to v16 and now I seem to have issues with Nginx when running `nginx -t`.

[image]

Here is the start of my `sites-enabled/default` which was preserved during the upgrade.

```
server_tokens off;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA$
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
add_header X-Xss-Protection "1";
```

Can someone advise on how to get around these issues.

**Extra Info**
Not entirely sure if it's relevant but I also had to create a new SSL certificate. I did this via the Digital Ocean control panel but haven't done anything beyond this.

Running `grep -r ssl_protocol /etc/nginx` I get:

[image]

Comment: I’m almost sure there is a backup file in sites-enabled

Comment: A backup of what though? This is the file I need - just not sure if there's something wrong with it?

Comment: Of `default`. Check `grep -r ssl_protocol /etc/nginx`

Comment: What I mean is - why do I need the backup?

Comment: You don’t. But probably Ubuntu create it during upgrade

Comment: And what impact does it have - what are you suggesting I do? I've run the command you suggested - see updated question

Comment: Well, not a backup. Just remove duplicate line from any of these files.

Comment: In `sites-enabled` there is just `default`. In `sites-available` there are `default`  and `default.dpkg-dist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these directives are actually duplicated.

One is in main configuration file `nginx.conf` and the other in `default`.

You need to change one or the other so it stops complaining. It must be unique to a given `server` context.

Comment: Unfortunately, documentation shows it also has the http `context` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt will manage these properties directly.  `Certbot` will add the following line to your `nginx.conf` file:

```
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
```

For Certbot to renew your SSL certs automatically, this file should not be edited.

Solution: remove (or #comment) duplicate `ssl_protocols`, `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers`, and `ssl_ciphers` from `nginx.conf`.